# Wait for a lock to unlock, without locking it after the unlock

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, locking

Sorry if the title is a tongue twister but I couldn't phrase it better since that's exactly what I want to do.

I have this method/code:

```
// No need fairness (false) the first to get it is good to go
private final Lock TEST = new ReentrantLock(false)

public methodCalledByMultipleThreads() {

    // 1st code section - no concurrency problems
    // regardless of what happen in section 2 a thread that just called
    // this function should always be able to run section 1

    // 2nd code section begin

    if (rare_condition && TEST.tryLocking()) {
        // check again to avoid limit cases where "rare_condition" value
        // is invalidated by another thread (who ran "important stuffs")
        // and just released/unlock TEST with "TEST.unlock();"
        if (check_rare_condition_again) {
            // ##### do "important stuffs" ##### 
            // release lock
            TEST.unlock();
        }
    }

    TEST.waitUntilUnlocked(); // this is what I actually would like to do
    // ##### do other stuffs ##### 

}
```

Of course "waitUntilUnlocked" should not lock "TEST" when the wait is ended. I've tried to get the wanted behavior with an hacky usage of Semaphore... which is really bad, semaphores are not made for that and also cause overhead in this case (internal permits count isn't counting anything... is just a fancy lock):

```
private final Lock TEST = new ReentrantLock(false)

// absurd high value (Integer.MAX_VALUE) for permits, to allow "virtually"
// infinite threads to works with this code
private final Semaphore SEM = new Semaphore(Integer.MAX_VALUE, true);

public methodCalledByMultipleThreads() {

    // 1st code section

    // 2nd code section begin

    if (rare_condition && TEST.tryLocking()) {
        if (check_rare_condition_again) {

            // waits to gets all permits
            SEM.acquireUninterruptibly(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            // ##### do important stuffs ##### 

            // release all permits
            SEM.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            // release lock
            TEST.unlock();
        }
    }
    // ask one permit
    SEM.acquireUninterruptibly();
    //  ##### do other stuffs ##### 
    // release one permit
    SEM.release();

}
```

The above solution is "works" (by luck on the actual implementation the code is enough slow to not cause any edge cases... for now) but is theoretically wrong since "SEM.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);" and "TEST.unlock();" should be one thing.

How can I get this behavior without this ugly hack?

Comment: You can try to use `CountDownLatch` for that if I understood what you need correctly

Comment: Is `LOCK` actually supposed to be `TEST`? But anyway, there’s no meaning behind “has been unlocked” when you don’t lock. It simply mean that anyone could acquire the lock while you’re executing “do other stuffs” or even before that, so why wait for it to get unlocked?